# Is it possible to render multi-coloured emojis with ImageMagick?

Tags: text, imagemagick, rmagick, emoji

I have a text that may contain emojis. I want to render it into JPEG image with RMagick (I can also use ImageMagick directly).

I was able to render only monochrome emojis with AndroidEmoji.ttf, but ImageMagick renders interrogation signs if I use AppleColorEmoji.ttf.
Here's how I do it:

```
require 'rmagick'
granite = Magick::ImageList.new('granite:')
canvas = Magick::ImageList.new
canvas.new_image(300, 100, Magick::TextureFill.new(granite))

input = "  "
text = Magick::Draw.new
text.font = 'AppleColorEmoji.ttf'
text.pointsize = 20
text.gravity = Magick::CenterGravity
text.annotate(canvas, 0, 0, 0, 0, input)
canvas.write('result.jpg')
```

Is it possible to render coloured emojis with ImageMagick or is there another tool that can help?

Comment: hey @endenis, any luck with this?

Comment: @agamov not so far. :( I made a hacky temporary solution by merging text images with emoji images (I split them with a regular expression).

Comment: As far a I know, you can only do that with PANGO in ImageMagick.

Answer (score 8):

You can use pango for text rendering (as of v6.7.6-3):

`convert pango:'Hello! How are you?' example.png`

Produces this image (using v7.0.8-36)

[image: example.png]

See https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#pango for more details on how to use pango with ImageMagick

---

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, using ImageMagick 7.0.8-36 (by compiling from source), which looks to have  this configuration

```
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

And it looks like I'm using Pangocairo 1.40.14

```
$ convert -list format | grep -i pango
    PANGO* r--   Pango Markup Language (Pangocairo 1.40.14)
```

Comment: What OS are you on?  How's your imagemagick configured?  Trying this on OSX High Sierra with pango, fontconfig and freetype enabled and the emoji's are empty

Comment: @Ruxton Updated my answer with the requested information :)

Comment: I'm a couple of point releases above these on OSX and it still renders empty spaces :(

Answer (score 3):

I think you are out of luck... [ImageMagick forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=23057).

I suppose you could save all the glyphs as PNG files and append them together to make a *"textspeak sentence"*

```
convert smile.png StupidShoeThing.png arnie.png +append txtspeak.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but It would be difficult to implement since I may have emojis inside text, like `Hello! How are you?`.