# Generate image from text using imagemagick convert with Apple color emojis font

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to create an image from a text containing emojis utf-8 chars using convert.
If I use monochromatic ttf fonts for emojis everything works as expected.
But If I try to use Apple Color Emojis TTF font, convert generate an empty image.
Why ?? Is it possible that ImageMagick does not support Apple Color Emojis font ?

I'm using ImageMagick 6.9.2-10

Comment: Duplicate question... http://stackoverflow.com/a/32476543/2836621

Comment: Both didn't get an answer. The topic on ImageMagick forum is dated 2013 and the answer was not clear about what the problem is and if there is any possible way to solve it. Is it possible that in two years ImageMagick did not improve support for such fonts ?

Comment: I re-opened the topic on the forum and I'll update with some test. It seems that freetype2 support the font, but for some reason ImageMagick (that use freetype) does not render it :-(