# ImageMagick: emoji in string gets written as question mark

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using ImageMagick (in NodeJS) to write a string on top of an svg image.

If the string has a standard unicode emoji in it, the gets rendered as "?".

> "This string has a  emoji in it"

Gets rendered as:

> "This string has a ? emoji in it"

Is there a way to get ImageMagick to render the string with the actual emoji?

Comment: When I Google `imagemagick emoji` there seems to be helpful info, is none of it useful?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Tried those already -- those solutions are for only rendering an emoji. But I'm trying to render a string that has alphanumeric characters with an emoji in the middle.

Comment: Yup, doesn’t seem to be possible at the moment unfortunately. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475060/is-it-possible-to-render-multi-coloured-emojis-with-imagemagick/32476543

Comment: @Pekka웃 I've seen a ton of apps generate images that have strings with emojis so it must be possible -- that question seems to be about rendering different colors of the emojis.

Comment: It certainly is possible. It’s just doesn’t appear to be possible *within ImageMagick.* This is a special feature that would need to be implemented... I’m sure it’ll be there eventually. Depending on what kind of server environment you are on, perhaps there’s a workaround, like running a headless web browser and having that render the string... not sure, a quick Google search doesn’t seem to be turning up anything useful

Comment: Hold on, I just went through that forum thread the linked Q&A links to. Check out the last message on the first page, someone claims to have gotten it to work with a specific constellation of Freetype and Ftview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ImageMagick admin in [this forum thread](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=23057&start=15) in July 2016:

> We made an initial attempt at supporting color Emoji's and could not get it working. We don't have an ETA on when we will add support. In the mean-time, any user is welcome to submit a patch against the current code base to support color Emoji's.

This is very likely the current state of affairs as of this moment.

[This answer](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=23057#p128933), however, claims that Freetype and a tool called ftview support rendering Emoji. Check it out, might be worth a try.

Comment: Looks like this is still an issue. :(